# Plug-in estimate empirical distribution function

Tags: statistics

in many lecture notes about the *Empirical Cumulative Distribution Function* (for example here https://www.win.tue.nl/~rmcastro/2WS17/files/ecdf_hist.pdf, p. 3, just to cite one source) I find the following equivalence:
$$\int g(x)dF_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}g(X_i) $$
where $F_n(x)$ is the Empirical Cumulative Distribution Function and $X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d random variables with distribution $F(x)$. The equation above is used to estimate $\int g(x)dF(x)$.

What is puzzling me is the equivalence: $F_n(x)$ is discontinuous, and even though we consider the subset where $F_n(x)$ is constant its derivative is zero.
So is not that equivalence formally wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: $dF(x)$ is not a derivative. Do you know the [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral)?

Comment: Thanks. Here a link to a theorem that can be used to prove it: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m321/step.pdf